# Mysql and Java-Jsp Forms using beans

Tags: java

I want to automatically populate some of the text fields of my jsp form based on the value the user input to the first text field using beans. The internal working should be to fetch this value say v1 from the text field and grab the values based on v1 from the database (Mysql). then it should place this values in the text fields assigned to it Can anyone help?

Comment: This question is a pretty good one, if you show what you have tried/ have found on it.

Comment: basically I have tried applying ajax but I think there is some problem with it. The form works find except this functionality

Comment: i created a new jsp page to get the values but .jsp pages don't take the MySQL command or may be i don't know exactly how to pass command for that as I am using beans.